# Sending message to RabbitMQ using JMS

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, jms

I am new to RabbitMQ and trying to send a message to RabbitMQ using JMS. I have the below standard JMS producer program:

```java
public void sendMessage() {
    Context context = null;
    ConnectionFactory factory = null;
    Destination destination = null;
    Connection connection = null;
    Session session = null;
    MessageProducer producer = null;

    Properties initialProperties = new Properties();
    initialProperties.put(InitialContext.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory");
    initialProperties.put(InitialContext.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://IP:PORT");
    initialProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "mquser");
    initialProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "Mquser@123");
    try {
        context = new InitialContext(initialProperties);
        factory = (QueueConnectionFactory) context.lookup("jms/RemoteConnectionFactory");

        System.out.println("Lookup Success");
        destination = (Destination) context.lookup("jms/queue/TestQueue");
        System.out.println("Queue lookup success");
        connection = factory.createConnection();
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        producer = session.createProducer(destination);

        String text = "8=FIX.4.49=7735=349=A56=B34=352=20200115-13:18:26.000 45=322222=D100208103222223=40558=Invalid FIX2ITFMsgType10=226";
        TextMessage textMessage = session.createTextMessage();
        textMessage.setText(text);
        connection.start();
        System.out.println("Going to send");
        producer.send(textMessage);
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getName() + "has sent a message : " + text);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (context != null) {
            try {
                context.close();
            } catch (NamingException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (JMSException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which I am using to send message to ActiveMQ Artemis embedded in JBoss EAP 7.2. As I have found in [this link](https://www.rabbitmq.com/jms-client.html) I will not be able to use the above program to send message to RabbitMQ, but will of the below parameters:

1. Username
2. Password
3. VirtualHost
4. Host
5. Port
6. DestinationName
7. ExchangeName
8. QueueName
9. RoutingKey

Can anyone give me an example of a standard program for sending message to RabbitMQ. I am using Spring Boot and can also use its features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot provides a RabbitTemplate that makes it easy to send messages:

```
@Component
public class Example {

  private final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

  public Example(RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
      this.rabbitTemplate = rabbitTemplate;
  }

  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
       rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(MessagingRabbitmqApplication.topicExchangeName, "foo.bar.baz", "Hello from RabbitMQ!");
  }
```

Please checkout the tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/

Please also read the Spring Boot documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-amqp

Comment: I went through the tutorial, but in that where to set the host, username, password, destination etc? Actually I am unable to relate it with a jms producer.

Comment: It is given that spring boot automatically creates connection factory. It will be great if you can give me an example of JMS with all the configurations required

Comment: Please also read the Spring Boot documentation. There you find the properties you have to set for RabbitMQ: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-amqp

Comment: I'm happy to help